# Issue with Cesium entity visibility control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, cesiumjs

I'm facing an issue with controlling the visibility of entities in Cesium.
sometimes it is abnormal when i changed the value of  checkedList
I'm trying to toggle the visibility of entities, but I'm experiencing unexpected behavior. The entities don't hide/show as expected.
like this

[image]

The left side is abnormal and the right side is normal display.

this is my thinking:

1. Upon the initial rendering of the component, create and categorize all points based on their IDs,then put then in diffent arrays，like entityType1Arr,entityType2Arr.
2. Utilize the `useState` hook to establish an array named `checkedList`, which will be linked to the Ant Design Checkbox component.
3. Implement a listener to monitor changes in the `checkList` array. When changes occur, dynamically adjust the `show` property of the associated entities. This approach enables real-time control over the visibility of entities based on the checked or unchecked state of the checkboxes.

```
useEffect(()=>{
     entityType1Arr.forEach((entity) => {
            entity.show = checkedList.includes("type1");
        });
entityType2Arr.forEach((entity) => {
            entity.show = checkedList.includes("type2");
        });
},[checkedList])
```